# Syntax highlighting for MicroEmacs

Tags: emacs

**How can you enable syntax for MicroEmacs?**

I [put the following unsuccessfully](http://www.mail-archive.com/ql-users@quanta.org.uk/msg03859.html) to my the file uelocal_rc in my HOME.

```
add-global-mode "HILITE"
```

I also put unsuccessfully the following command both to .emacs and to uelocal_rc at my HOME.

```
(require 'font-lock)    ; enable syntax highlighting
```

This suggests me that .emacs does not manipulate Mg. 
It is also possible that the name of the file `uelocal_rc` is not correct, since I could not find any example of such files by Google and in Github.

I am using a fresh Ubuntu installation where the standard Emacs has no syntax highlighting.

I finally changed the file endings to .el but the problem remains.

I downloaded the source of MicroEmacs by

```
apt-get source mg
```

However, I did not find any help file by `ack-grep -i help/readme.`

I added the following lines to my .zshrc unsuccessfully.

```
# MicroEmacs                                                                    
export MEINSTALLPATH="/home/masi/"
export MEPATH="/home/masi/"
export MEUSERPATH='/home/masi/'
```

Comment: If MicroEmacs lacks lisp, would this be better on SuperUser (on account of being configuration rather than programming related)?

Comment: Pretty sure mg does not provide syntax highlighting.  If you want advanced features, just use the real Emacs.

Comment: BTW: qemacs provides *some* highlighting in a smaller (but still lisp-free) package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MicroEmacs, but there is a detailed chapter on [User Profiles in MicroEmacs's documentation](http://www.jasspa.com/me/m2nar003.html).

> The private user profile is stored in
>   a separate directory. The directory
>   that MicroEmacs uses is typically
>   automatically created at start up, but
>   may be created manually by the user.
>   If the directory is to be placed in a
>   special location then the
>   [$MEUSERPATH(5)](http://www.jasspa.com/me/m5var090.html) environment
>   variable should be defined and set to
>   point at this directory location.
>
> […]
>
> Users start-up file
>   [$user-name.emf](http://www.jasspa.com/me/m5var088.html) (see [emf(8)](http://www.jasspa.com/me/m8fil003.html)).
>   This is typically referred to as
>   "*user.emf*" in the documentation and
>   means the users private MicroEmacs
>   macro file. The user may make local
>   changes to MicroEmacs in this file,
>   this may include definition of new key
>   bindings, defining new hook functions
>   etc. You should override the standard
>   MicroEmacs settings from your start-up
>   file rather than modifying the
>   standard MicroEmacs files.

And yes, it skips parsing `.emacs` according to the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MicroEmacs) as ‘[i]t lacks EmacsLisp, but offers its own sort of extension language’.

Comment: Thank you for the link! - I copied the example `user.emf` while to my HOME with the `add-global-mode "HILITE"` unsucessfully, while I removed my `.emacs` at my HOME.  - I also added a few lines to my .zshrc which are in my question.

Comment: The documentation is for the Jasspa edition of MicroEmacs. There may be differences between the Jasspa edition and the default MicroEmacs edition which is in the apt-get as `Mg`.